# Last selected Row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView, in which if any row is selected i am storing some values. If any other row is selected i am displaying an alertView with warning that his previous selection will be gone. This alerView has 2 buttons YES and NO. If YES is selected go on to selecting the new row which is fine. But if no is selected i want reselect the previous row. I can post the code if asked. But it seems more of logical question than code oriented.

Thank you.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: how do i get the last selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first store the clicked tableview index to your global variable in `UITableView Delegate` like below,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView==yourTableview) {
        yourMemberVariable=[indexPath row];
  }
}
```

then check `yourMemberVariable` in `UIAlertView delegate`

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)//OK button pressed
    {
       //do something
    }else{
    if(yourMemberVariable>someValue){ //perform your own conditions whatever
       [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourMemberVariable   inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: kk... ill try to initialize it with -1 first.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the last row selected ,you can do this by setting

```
    tableView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = true
```

in viewDidLoad function.

and then calling

```
   tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

wherever required.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just save previous row into class member. Good luck!

Comment: AFAIK uitableview dosen't save history, so there is no inbuilt methods. You can write your own class based on uitableview with saving history, but I thinks that's hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the last selected item. On the select delegate for the table, store what was selected in a variable accessible througout the class.

```
NSInteger selectedRow = 0;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedRow = [indexPath row];
}
```

Now you know what element to select if NO is pressed in the UIAlertView delegate

```
[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRow inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Comment: the row gets stored even the 1st time the user selects a row. I want to display msg only after second selection, that he is changing the row. In this the msg comes even the 1st time he is selecting.

Comment: Start with selectedRow = -1. In you didSelectRowAtIndexPath check if selectedRow is greater or equal to zero, then you know a previous selection exists.